# How to make log-in with Django rest api

Tags: django, rest, server, backend

hello i learning about Django rest api, I am learning through someone else's code, but I don't know how to make Login.

my code :

model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "users"

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    updated_ay = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 128, unique= True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    token = models.CharField(max_length= 255, null = True)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null = True)
```

serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        ret = super(UserSerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)

        # cipher = AESSipher()
        # ret['password'] = cipher.encrypt_str(ret['password'])

        return ret

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        ret = super(UserSerializer, self).to_representation(obj)
        print(ret)
        return ret

    def validate_email(self, value):
        if User.objects.filter(email=value).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Email already exists")
        return value

    def validate_password(self, value):
        if len(value) < 8:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("The password must be at least %s characters long. " % 8)
        return value

    def create(self, validate_data):
        user = User.objects.create(
            email = validate_data['email'],
            password = validate_data['password'],
        )

        user.active = False
        user.save()

        message = render_to_string('user/account_activate_email.html', {
            'user': user,
            'domain' : 'localhost:8000',
            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
            'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user)
        })


        mail_subject = 'sign up mail.'
        to_email = 'mymail@gmail.com'
        email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
        email.send()

        return validate_data
```

views:

```
class SignUp(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)




class UserActivate(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request, uidb64, token):
        try:
            uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
            user = User.objects.get(pk = uid)
        except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
            user = None
        try:
            if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
                user.active = True
                user.token = token
                user.save()
                return Response(user.email + 'email active', status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                return Response('Expired Link', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        except Exception as e:
            print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Since I want to handle log-in status in the Mobile Client section, 
I want to get only user model information when I log-in.

When Enter Email and Password in Client and I want to get user information.

How to make log-in? Do you know anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to the article: custom user authentication; it should help you
https://wsvincent.com/django-rest-framework-user-authentication-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use Django packages for this. for example you can use rest-auth package this package have all the things that you need for log in log out and reset password and all you need is that follow the rest auth documentation :
. https://pypi.org/project/django-rest-auth/
. https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/